# Best way to store the quantity of Stock of different types in sql

Tags: c#, sql, database

I want to store the Quantity of Stocks given by user in database.
I can't find the best way of doing it.

I have tried it as following.

[image]

Above image is showing the structure of Stock Table from Database.
There are two columns(QuantityByWeights, QuantityByPacks) in this table from which one will be surely null. Because A product will be stored as weight or as by Packs.
And other will have the Value.

Problem here is if a product is stored as QuantityByPacks, I want to store the Unit Weight of a pack also. I can't find the way of doing this

Comment: Why not add a column called `UnitWeight` and store it in that?

Comment: At the very least you need another column to handle this information. Say something like 'PackWeight'

Comment: @GarethD So If i made an int column UnitWeight then, What if i want to store 'KG' or 'Grams' at its end? or A new Column also for it?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this kind of data modeling if you have only one quantity for each product:

Product table:

```
Id                 integer
product_name       varchar
quantity           varchar
quantity_type_id   integer    FK
```

quantity_type table:

```
id              integer
description     varchar
```

This is the easiest way. Not the most professional way.

**Update:**

If you have different kind of quantity for each product, like size and weight, a better solution might be:

Product table:

```
Id                 integer
product_name       varchar
```

quantity_type table:

```
id              integer
description     varchar
```

product_quantity table:

```
product_id        integer
quantity_type_id  integer
value             varchar
```